# As an admin, how can I view individual user permissions for individual nodes?

Tags: commerce, users

I’m attempting to sell individual nodes (video classes) to individual customers on my client’s website. I've learned how to do this via two videos from Commerce Guys website. It uses the following modules:

Content_Access, ACL, References, Rules, Commerce

Briefly it works like this: 
Two content types are created - a video class product, a video class. Each video class product has  a reference to a video class. Once purchased an individual then has permission granted to view the video class, the one ref’d by the video class product. By default video class content type permissions are turned off. But on the access control tab of the content type there is an option that is checked that reads ‘Enable per content node access control settings’

My question is this: As an admin how can i view an individual user’s permission setting for individual nodes? and then change that permission?

I’m asking because although it works initially, at some point the user’s permissions are being being reset, ie turned off and I’m not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Node Access". After enabling it, you can add it as a block. It shows you a table with detailed permission for each content.

Answer (score 0):

On the video class nodes page, by way of the access_control module there is an access control tab. On that page, toward the bottom there is a section labeled ‘USER ACCESS CONTROL LISTS’. From there you can set individual user permissions.

Comment: Sorry I did see this until after I posted the question! But the problem remains that user permissions for a node are being turned off somehow and i need to figure out why